# converting c#.net application to android

Tags: c#, android

I know this is very vaque question but still I am asking.

Is there any one I can convert my existing WinForm built in c#.net and DB as SQLSERVER 2008, to andorid application ?
If no, then is thr any easier way to built an app as I am not familiar with any Mobile Application tools.

Comment: No, but C# is close enough to Java to do most of the work with little effort.  To produce the app, you have 2 choices.  Learn, or pay someone to do it.

Comment: I Can do it for $24/hr... :)

Answer (score 2):

Generally, no. The languages are somewhat similar, but the way the UI is built is vastly different and will have to be rewritten from scratch. Also, database access differs. I actually doubt that Android have libraries required to "talk" to SqlServer. Even if it managed to talk over some generic ODBC layer, still the DB-access will also differ very much. I assume this would consist of more than 80% of your application - so it can safely be estimated that whole application cannot be converted, and a new application has to be written. Of course, some SQL queries might be reused, some application classes might be usable too (if written in an enough platform-independent way, so they can be translated to Java)..

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to do that in *easy* way. 
Android development is similiar in UI level to WPF (you *can* find some simliarities) + you have *completely* different behavior model as you're talking about mobile development.

In short, if you want to continue with C#, you may think of picking [Mono Droid](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid).
It's payed.

Answer (score 0):

This is not easy as far as I know. If you want the conversion for free you should rewrite it in Java using the Android SDK (run on Dalvik - a custom VM). As stated above, you will have little effort learning it if you already know C#, you could also use Mono Droid or hire a developer if you have the possibility to do so.

Comment: Learning the language is a little effort, but learning the **platform** and the **libraries** and the application architecture and (...) is a completely non-little effort!

Comment: Exactly, this is why you could opt for a solution with a higher cost instead.